# React app not working on AWS S3 server inside a static index.html file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3, redux, react-router

I have a react, redux app which works very well on my local webpack-dev-server. But I am trying to run the same on s3 by pushing the the build created by

```
"webpack --optimize-minimize --define process.env.NODE_ENV='production'"
```

After uploading the build to S3 and trying to open the index.htm fails and I keep getting an empty react element on my dom

```
<div id="content" class="content">
   <!-- react-empty: 1 -->
</div>
```

As you can see the element where I am trying to mount react ('content') is present in the HTML. Also I the container div is before the  tag to load app.js.(If that makes any difference). Also I am using 'browserHistory' from 'react-router' inside my react app.

```
const store = configureStore();
    ReactDOM.render(
        <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Routes />
            </Provider>
    </MuiThemeProvider>, document.getElementById('content'));
```

my index file is as follows ( I change the paths of style.css and app.js to the S3 path before uploading)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing App</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../scheduling-buildfiles/public/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class='header'>Header Here</div>
<div id='content' class='content'>Content Here</div>
<div class='footer'>Footer Here</div>
<script src="../scheduling-buildfiles/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my routes look something like:

```
'use strict';
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute  } from 'react-router';
//import components here

export default class Routes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history = {browserHistory}>
        <Route path = "/" component={Main}>
          <IndexRoute component = {LoginComponent} />
                    <Route path="/addVehicle" component={AddVehicleComponent} />
                    <Route path="/selectServices" component={SelectServicesComponent}/>
                    <Route path="/findServices" component={FindServicesComponent} />
                    <Route path="/bookAppointment" component={BookAppointmentComponent}/>
                    <Route path="/myInformation" component={MyInformationComponent}/>
                    <Route path="/appointmentSummary" component={AppointmentSummaryComponent}/>
        </Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Any idea what the issue might be or how to troubleshoot it further ? Or if anyone has a simple example of doing a similar thing? The purpose is to make sure that my app can run on another persons index.html by just adding the script tag for app.js and a container "content" to startup my app.

Comment: Please provide some details about your app, routes etc.

Comment: Did that above. @Koen.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution.It works if I replace browserHistory with hashHistory.

But not sure the reasoning behind it. If anyone knows about it, please enlighten me. Any explanations/resources are welcome.